# vue cli axios mixing array indexes when getting requests

Tags: vue.js, axios

```
const sentenc = this.colocation[0][i].examples;
            sentenc.forEach((item,index) => {
            var colAction = this.colocation[0][i].examples[index];
            const strippedString = colAction.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");
 this.examplesEN.push(strippedString)
              axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key={apikey}='+strippedString+'&source=en&target=tr')
                .then((response) =>{
                  const exTranslet = response.data.data.translations[0].translatedText;
                  this.examplesTR.push(exTranslet);
                 
                })
          })
```

I am building a translator with using 2 different apis. While i pushing english colocations to array, cant pushing turkish colocations to another array to same index numbers. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but axios doing another loop selfly and mixing array indexes. For example;

```
for(i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
      //your axios codes
       {
          //i = 0
          //i = 3
          //i = 2
          //i = 4
          //i = 1
       }
   //i = 0
   //i = 1
   //i = 2
   //i = 3
   //i = 4
    }
```

You should push your all datas to array in axios. Like ;

```
const sentenc = this.colocation[0][i].examples;
            sentenc.forEach((item,index) => {
            var colAction = this.colocation[0][i].examples[index];
            const strippedString = colAction.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");
              axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key={apikey}='+strippedString+'&source=en&target=tr')
                .then((response) =>{
                  const exTranslet = response.data.data.translations[0].translatedText;
                  this.examplesTR.push(exTranslet);
                  this.examplesEN.push(strippedString) //use this line in axios
                })
          })
```